# What controls logEvent.FormattedMessage?

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm using a MethodCallTarget to capture log output and display it in a diagnostic window:

```
MethodCallTarget target = new MethodCallTarget("MyTarget", 
     (logEvent, parms) => WriteMessage(logEvent.FormattedMessage));
```

MethodCallTarget does not include a Layout parameter.  **So how would I have FormattedMessage include the call stack in the case of exceptions?**

I realize I could make the target method format the message however I like, but I'm trying to understand the relationship between Layout and FormattedMessage and if I can change the default functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is this:

```
MethodCallTarget target = new MethodCallTarget("MyTarget", 
     (logEvent, parms) => WriteMessage(logEvent.Exception != null ? string.Concat(logEvent.FormattedMessage, " Exception: ", logEvent.Exception.ToString()) : logEvent.FormattedMessage);
```

If you want make use of the NLog Layout logic, then you can do it like this:

```
MethodCallTarget target = new MethodCallTarget("MyTarget", 
     (logEvent, parms) => WriteMessage(parms[0].ToString()));
target.Parameters.Add(new MethodCallParameter("AdvancedMessage", "${message}${onexception:EXCEPTION OCCURRED\:${exception:format=tostring}}"));
```